# trace changes car/set-car! behavior

Tags: scheme

I found some extremely confusing behavior which I suspect is a bug in my Scheme interpreter, but experience has told me that I am almost definitely incorrect. I am using Petite Chez Scheme, version 9.4.1.

```
(let ((a '(0))) (set-car! a 9) (car a))
```

On my interpreter, this code returns `0` and not `9`. Even more confusingly, if I run

```
(trace car)
(untrace car)
(let ((a '(0))) (set-car! a 9) (car a))
```

I get `9`, which is what I expected in the first place. What on Earth is going on here? Is something bizarre going on with scopes and pointers? Should I file this as a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that this is invalid Scheme code. According to the reports (all of them) you are mutating literal data. Imagine this example here in R5RS:

```
(define test '(1 2 3))
(define (get-some-list)
  '(1 2 3))
(set-car! test 5)
(gen-some-list)
; ==> (5 2 3)
```

As you see the program has spotted you use the literal list `(1 2 3)` twice and since you are not allowed to change those it has optimized it by using the same object for both since they are the same. Being R5RS using `set-car!` on it it's optional to signal an error, not doing anything or actually updating the literal data. Being undefined it's up to the implementer. Actually evaluating `test` and getting `(1 2 3)` is perfectly ok too.

In R6RS it should raise **&assertion exception** [according to the report](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs-lib/r6rs-lib-Z-H-18.html#node_idx_1274).

```
#!r6rs
(import (rnrs)
        (rnrs mutable-pairs))

(define (g) '(constant-list))
(set-car! (g) 3) ⇒  unspecified
; should raise  &assertion exception
```

This tells you two things. Having a function return immutable data does not waive the rule and doing any of these should also raise &assertion exception:

```
(set-car! '(constant-list) 3) ⇒  unspecified
; should raise  &assertion exception

(define const '(constant-list))
(set-car! const 3) ⇒  unspecified
; should raise  &assertion exception
```

The same code as in your question as valid Scheme:

```
#!r6rs
(import (rnrs)
        (rnrs mutable-pairs))

(let ((a (list 0))) 
  (set-car! a 9) 
  (car a))
 ⇒  9
```

Comment: I did not realize that quoted lists were constants until these answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that you are modifying `a` which is bound to a *costant* value `'(0)`. Depending on the specific interpreter/compiler, this operation is undefined (for instance in other implementations the value returned is 9).

Instead, by modifying a value built with the `list` operator, the operation is correctly performed in any implementation, including Petite Chez Scheme:

```
(let ((a (list 0))) (set-car! a 9) (car a))  ;; => 9
```

Comment: Is this to say that it does not matter that `trace` changing the behavior does not matter, because it is already an undefined operation?

Comment: Yes. Trace could modify something in the execution of primitive functions inside the interpreter.

Comment: It seems absurd to me that you can even run a `set!` operation on an immutable structure without an exception, but this is a helpful answer as to why I get the results that I do.

Comment: Well, when something is declared “undefined behaviour” in a language, implementations are free to manage it in any way, including crashing, signalling a useful or unuseful error, producing the apparently intuitive result, etc., even behaving in a counter-intuitive way!